# i keep getting list iterator not dereferencable, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with with this project of mine. i want it to draw out an octagon, the code i used worked perfectly fine for other shapes like rhombus and triangle.

the octagon.cpp file http://pastebin.com/iVfdkKEB

the header file http://pastebin.com/a50UQi5F

the main part which runs it all http://pastebin.com/quepi6az

```
#include "shape.h"
class Octagon : public Shape
{
int radius;

void plotVertices();
public:
Octagon(Vertex point, int radius = 10);
int area();
int perimeter();
};

#include "octagon.h"

Octagon::Octagon(Vertex point, int radius) : Shape(point)
{
// constructs a Octagon of radius around a point in 2D space
if ((radius>centroid.getX() / 2) || (radius>centroid.getX() / 2))
{
    cout << "Object must fit on screen." << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
    this->radius = radius;
    plotVertices();
}
// place your code here and add comments that describe your understanding of what is happening

}
void Octagon::plotVertices()
{

int x, y, _x, _y; // declare and intiliase variables for x and y co-ordinates
double radians;

x = centroid.getX(); // places first point A at the centroid
y = centroid.getY() + radius;
vertices.push_back(Vertex(x, y));

x = vertices.back().getX() - centroid.getX();
y = vertices.back().getY() - centroid.getY();

for (int i = 45; i < 360; i += 45) // for loop to draw the shape itself by creating the points.
    // i = size of interior angle.
{
    radians = i * PI / 180;
    _x = round(x * cos(radians) - y * sin(radians));
    _y = round(y* cos(radians) + x * sin(radians));
    _x = _x + centroid.getX();
    _y = _y + centroid.getY();
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(_x, _y));
}
}


#pragma once

#include "vertex.h"
#include "shape.h"
#include "octagon.h"
#include "console.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
list<Shape*> shapes;

int x = 20, y = 60;
shapes.push_back(new Octagon(Vertex(20, 60), 8));

list<Shape*>::iterator itr = shapes.begin();
while(itr!=shapes.end())
{
    (*itr)->drawShape();
    system("pause");
    (*itr)->outputStatistics();
    // output shape statistics
    (*itr)->scale(2.0);
    (*itr)->drawShape();
    // scale shape (double it)
    // draw shape
    (*itr)->rotate(20);
    (*itr)->drawShape();
    // rotate shape by 20 degrees
    // draw shape
    itr++;
}

Console::gotoXY(0,0);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

and the draw shape function

```
void Shape::drawShape()
{
// plots each vertex and draws a line between them using Bresenham's algorithm
// you can adjust your console font and dimensions if you want to increase the resolution of your shapes

list<Vertex>::iterator current = vertices.begin();
list<Vertex>::iterator previous = vertices.begin();
while (current != vertices.end())
{
    Console::gotoXY((*current).getX(), (*current).getY());
    cout << "*";
    if (current != vertices.begin())
        drawLine((*current).getX(), (*current).getY(), (*previous).getX(), (*previous).getY());
    previous = current;
    current++;
}
drawLine(vertices.back().getX(), vertices.back().getY(), vertices.front().getX(), vertices.front().getY());
}
```

Comment: Please post you code as text and provide an [mcve] in your question.

Comment: I can't see any reason for this code to produce that error. Mind you, you call a bunch of functions that do god knows what. Present your [MCVE].

Comment: really? yea it's for a coursework, I have to draw out shapes, scale and then rotate them. it worked perfectly fine for previous shapes but it won't even draw an octagon. is there something i might have missed?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: And where you getting it?

Comment: @Alex it compiles fine, when it runs it crashes saying list iterator not dereferencable.

Comment: @max66 Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP120D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list
Line: 210

Expression: list iterator not dereferencable

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from sure, but I think that the problem can be in the last line of `void Shape::drawShape()`

```
drawLine(vertices.back().getX(), vertices.back().getY(), vertices.front().getX(), vertices.front().getY());
```

where isn't a check to see if `vertices` is empty. In that case, `vertices.back()` and `vertices.front()` are undefined (both equal to `vertices.end()`?) and dereferencing they, to call `getX()` and `getY()`, can cause your problem.

It's possible an empty `vertices`? I don't know because I don't see all code but I see that there is an `exit(0)` in the `if` body of the `Octagon` constructor.

It's `plotVertices()` that populate `vertices`? In this case, the `exit(0)` say us that `vertices` is empty and that the last `drawline()` in `Shape::drawshape` can cause the trouble.

The solution (a solution) is obvious and simple: check if `vertices` is empty

```
if ( false == vertices.empty() )
   drawLine(vertices.back().getX(), vertices.back().getY(), vertices.front().getX(), vertices.front().getY());
```